# Akka two receiveBuilder in same class

Tags: java, akka

Working with legacy code, inside class which is extended to BaseActor, there two entry points for process messages like that:

```
 private Receive active = receiveBuilder().matchAny((message) -> { 
    
 if(message instanceof String){
    some code
   } else if(...) {
    //some code} else {
    //some code}
   }
```

and this receiver:

```
 @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        
        return receiveBuilder().matchAny((message) -> {
          if(message instanceof String){
    some code
   } else if(...) {
    //some code} else {
    //some code}
   }
         }
```

i know that there are typed and untyped actors, but its confusing when enters into active and when into createReceive;
When testing locally always enters into createReceive, on server it enters into active.
if there is only createReceive declared and not active it uses createReceive.
what logic works here, or where i can find docs for it. checked doc.akka.io but still not clear

Answer (score 1):

Receive by itself doesn't do anything : Its just Java glue around class pattern matching. You either return Receive from the createReceive() method (the actors initial pattern matching message loop), or in a getContext.become() call, which then replaces the current active pattern matching message loop with a new one.

The above is described https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html